# How does Rust know what type is parsed by parse_utf8?

Tags: rust

I have a custom enum type, `ValueString`, which contains two variants: `Integer(i64)` and `Data(Vec<u8>)`. I've written a function called `parse_utf8`, which takes a generic type `T` and attempts to parse a value from `newvalue`, returning `Option<T>`.

In my `ValueString::new` method, I want to be able to create different variants of `ValueString` based on the type parsed by `parse_utf8`. If the parsed type is i64, I will create `ValueString::Integer(i)`; otherwise, I will create `ValueString::Data(newValue)`.

However, I don't understand how Rust knows that the type within `Some(i)` is `i64`.

```
pub enum ValueString {
    Integer(i64),
    Data(Vec<u8>),
}

fn parse_utf8<T: str::FromStr>(newvalue: &[u8]) -> Option<T> {
    if let Some(b'0') = newvalue.first() {
        None
    } else {
        str::from_utf8(newvalue).ok().and_then(|s| s.parse().ok())
    }
}

impl ValueString {
    pub fn new(newValue: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        match parse_utf8(&newValue) {
            Some(i) => ValueString::Integer(i),
            None => ValueString::Data(newValue),
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to determine the type of the value returned by `parse_utf8` and expected to identify whether it's an `i64` or not. However, I encountered a type mismatch error when attempting to create the appropriate variant of `ValueString`. I expected to be able to create a `ValueString::Integer(i)` if the parsed type is `i64`, but I'm not sure how to perform this type check.

Comment: Because it has to be? The compiler works backwards: `ValueString::Integer` takes an i64, so `parse_utf8` has to return an `Option<i64>`, and since `i64` does implement `FromStr` the compiler instantiates `parse_utf8::<i64>` and uses that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other languages, the Rust compiler can intuit the type of most values.  This is very useful because many types, such as those of iterator chains, can be very complex, and having to specify them manually, as in older versions of C++, is unergonomic and a big hassle.

The compiler knows that `parse_utf8` returns an `Option<T>`.  It can look at the `Some` variant, which must contain a `T`.  When matching the `Some` variant, the value `i`, which is of type `T`, is inserted into a `ValueString::Integer`, which must have an `i64`.  Thus, `T` must be `i64` if the code is to be valid, so it picks that value.

If you'd written `Some(i) => ValueString::Integer(i as i64)`, then the compiler wouldn't be able to determine what the type is, because there are a variety of built-in types that can be cast to an `i64`, so you'd have to specify directly.  There are also other cases where it may need help, even when it's obvious to a human what was intended, and then you also need to specify explicitly.